# Failure to compile kdesvn from source

Tags: software-installation, kde

I'm running Ubuntu 16.04 which does not have a `kdesvn` package. I wanted to compile `kdesvn` from sources, `cmake` all goes through fine after I installed all dependencies but the compilation gets stuck at:

```
[ 78%] Building CXX object src/svnfrontend/CMakeFiles/svnfrontend.dir/maintreewidget.cpp.o
/home/ron/src/kdesvn/src/svnfrontend/maintreewidget.cpp: In member function ‘void MainTreeWidget::enableActions()’:
/home/ron/src/kdesvn/src/svnfrontend/maintreewidget.cpp:826:46: error: ‘authorizeAction’ is not a member of ‘KAuthorized’
     enableAction(QStringLiteral("openwith"), KAuthorized::authorizeAction("openwith") && single && !single_dir);
                                              ^
src/svnfrontend/CMakeFiles/svnfrontend.dir/build.make:850: recipe for target 'src/svnfrontend/CMakeFiles/svnfrontend.dir/maintreewidget.cpp.o' failed
make[2]: *** [src/svnfrontend/CMakeFiles/svnfrontend.dir/maintreewidget.cpp.o] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:764: recipe for target 'src/svnfrontend/CMakeFiles/svnfrontend.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [src/svnfrontend/CMakeFiles/svnfrontend.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:138: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Why is this and how can I fix it?

I have verified that **libkf5config-dev** is installed, it contains `KAuthorized`: https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/amd64/libkf5config-dev/filelist

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Compiling kdesvn under Xenial Xerus 16.04 can be done but there is
certainly some work to be done and quite a raft of dependencies
to download and install. I give the full method below, follow this
and you should achieve (as I have) a working copy of kdesvn under Xenial.

*Note that compiling this application is reasonably arduous and there is a decent PPA for an older version of `kdesvn`. Details in the 'Notes' section of this answer below.*

**1. Add a required PPA**

Some updated kde libraries are required and this rather big PPA
contains the libraries you will need:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:kubuntu-ppa/backports
sudo apt-get update
```

**2. Add in the dependencies**

The following is *a single command*, simply copy and paste into a Terminal window:

```
sudo apt-get install \
cmake debhelper extra-cmake-modules gettext libkf5bookmarks-dev \
libkf5config-dev libkf5configwidgets-dev libkf5coreaddons-dev \
libkf5dbusaddons-dev libkf5doctools-dev libkf5i18n-dev \
libkf5iconthemes-dev libkf5itemviews-dev libkf5kio-dev \
libkf5notifications-dev libkf5parts-dev libkf5service-dev \
libkf5texteditor-dev libkf5wallet-dev libkf5widgetsaddons-dev \
libsvn-dev pkg-kde-tools qtbase5-dev build-essential checkinstall
```

**3. Download and compile the latest kdesvn**

We can use the very latest version of kdesvn, this will be downloaded,
compiled and installed with the following *single command*:

```
mkdir $HOME/kdesvn_build && cd $HOME/kdesvn_build && \
wget https://download.kde.org/stable/kdesvn/2.0.0/kdesvn-2.0.0.tar.xz && \
tar xvf kdesvn-2.0.0.tar.xz && cd kdesvn-2.0.0 && \
sed -i_bak 's/Exec=kdesvn -caption "%c" %u/Exec=kdesvn/' src/org.kde.kdesvn.desktop && \
mkdir build && cd build && cmake -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr .. && make && \
sudo checkinstall -D --install=yes --fstrans=no --pakdir "$HOME/kdesvn_build" \
   --pkgname kdesvn --backup=no --deldoc=yes --deldesc=yes --delspec=yes --default \
   --pkgversion "2.0.0"
```

*Note the small `sed` adjustment to the source code desktop file for `kdesvn`
without which the application will not run from a graphical launcher.*

**4. Run kdesvn:**

All running well on my Xenial system as the following screenshot demonstrates:

[image]

And should run as well on your own system!!

**Notes:**

- If you are happy to simply use a PPA rather than compile `kdesvn` you can get a slightly older version (1.7.0) with the following PPA:

  ```
  sudo add-apt-repository ppa:dominik-stadler/dsta-xenial-ppa
  sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install kdesvn
  ```

  This was perfectly usable on my Xenial system....
- If you are happy with the final result you can then safely delete the
  build directory completely:

  ```
  rm -rfv $HOME/kdesvn_build
  ```

Comment: The problem is, I cannot add `ppa`s, I think it might be blocked by our firewall, I get: `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:kubuntu-ppa/backports`:`Cannot add PPA: 'ppa:~kubuntu-ppa/ubuntu/backports'.
ERROR: '~kubuntu-ppa' user or team does not exist.` and it's the same for all ppas I've tried...

Comment: askubuntu has a few questions and successful answers for this issue. You unfortunately need the PPAs for this to succeed...

Comment: but really, it should be possible without the PPAs, too should it not...I don't see why not, if I compile everything required from source... I've tried a few other SVN clients in the meantime but haven't found a good alternative to kdesvn yet... :(

Comment: Unfortunately I have been unable to compile the most recent kdesvn under Xenial without the use of these PPAs and updated libraries :(

Comment: @ansrew.46 I'm now trying to compile `kdesvn` on my personal `xenial` machine and will try to just copy the binary (and dependencies)across manually...i'll see if that yields any success. I've been struggling finding another decent graphical svn client, i've tried it all else by now i think, not liking anything really other than kdesvn, some combination of shell based svn along with `meld` has been the best alternative....